# Returning an int* from ASM

Tags: c, pointers, assembly

I'm writing a function in ASM which is supposed to copy the (constant) value 2 into every index of an array declared in .data. My code compiles, but I don't get any output through my C program. Here's the code:

```
        .globl my_func
        .globl _my_func

my_func:
_my_func:
    movl    %esp,%ebp
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    $0,%ecx
    leal    array,%eax
    jmp     continue


continue:
_continue:
    movl    $2,array(%ecx,4)
    cmpl    $1024,%ecx
    jne     incr
    je      finish

incr:
_incr:
    addl    $4,%ecx
    jmp     continue


finish:
_finish:
    popl    %ebp
    ret

        .data

    .align 4
array:  .fill   1024
```

It is called from here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int* my_func();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int* a = my_func();
    for(i = 0; i < 1024/4; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned, the program does compile and run, but the main function does not output anything to the terminal. And yes, I know the code isn't optimal -- I'm currently following an introductory course in computer architecture and ASM, and I'm just checking out instructions and data.

I am assembling the code for IA32 on an Intel Mac with OSX10.9, using LLVM5.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you running this on, and how are you compiling the program? (e.g. 32-bit vs 64-bit OS/program would matter).

Comment: You should change `1024/4` in the `for` loop to `1024 / sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @ajay That made no difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: Look at the memory pointed to by `a` just after the call to `my_func`. Step into `my_func` with disassembled code and look what's going on. Maybe the compiler expects the return value in another register than eax.

Comment: Your `movl` and `pushl` at the start of the function appear to be in the wrong order.

Comment: @Michael That's actually it! Thank you! Post it as an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function prologue where you save the previous frame pointer and set it up for the new stack frame should be:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp,%ebp
```

Yours is in the opposite order, so when your function returns the caller's frame pointer will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

return values are normally in `eax`, so you need to set `eax` to the address of the start of the memory you want to return in `finish`.

fyi: you shouldn't need to declare your label twice, the leading underscore is only needed for public functions you want to access from C

Comment: There's a `leal    array,%eax` at the beginning of the function, and I can't see `eax` being modified between there and the return point.

Comment: OP is already assigning the address to eax at the beginning of the function with `leal  array,%eax`.

Comment: missed that - oops.
If you printf the value of a what do you get, is it the same everytime time?  printf("%p", a);